# Does boost::multi_array default initialize its contents?

Tags: boost, boost-multi-array

`std::vector<T> foo(100)` initialises every element with the default value for `T`. Does `boost::multi_array<T, 2> foo(boost::extents[10][10])` do the same?

Answer (score 1):

It does, using `std::allocator::construct()` by default.

Comment: That is right, and `construct` calls `new(p) U();` which initializes to zero even for trivial types. I think this choice is a mistake for trivial types for performance and debuggability reasons (it is not possible to detect initialized memory because of this forced initialization).